# iOS ShareKit issue with facebook popup webview. User not able to see the "Cancel", "Allow" buttons for newly created users

Tags: ios, facebook, permissions, sharekit

Since Facebook introduced it's "profile completion messages", trying to log in and allow the app to give permissions for a user without friends or photos, will block the user to reach the "Cancel" and "Allow" buttons on the bottom of the page.

See a screenshot attached.
[image]

It seems like the web view is not scrollable.

I'm using Sharekit 2.0 sdk.

Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, but only on new Facebook accounts. Any idea what's causing the problem?